# Is it possible to merge / intersect two UIViews rather than have them overlap?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, core-graphics

Given two `UIViews` with borders that have `UIPanGestureRecognizers` attached to them:

[image]

If I drag the `UIView` on the left over the `UIView` on the right, this is the usual behavior:

[image]

Is it possible to get them to do the behavior below where it looks like they merge?[image]:

Looking for the simplest way possible to do this!

Comment: Have you tried with transparency on both the views? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40405278/swift-uiview-opacity-programmatically

Comment: @TarunLalwani I haven't, that's an interesting idea. Would it be possible to do without changing the look of the UIViews? If I made the top view transparent, wouldn't the border of the bottom view shine through?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One way is to use multiple **sibling** layers and [`zPosition`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410884-zposition). To achieve the effect you add two layers, one for border, one for content. And the border layer has a smaller `zPosition` than the content. And, of course, move the layers with the `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.

[image: Showcase]

[MP4 version](https://i.imgur.com/bHIrCBG.mp4)

Swift:

```
import UIKit

class MergingView: UIView {

    let borderLayer = CALayer()
    let backgroundLayer = CALayer()

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        addGestureRecognizer(UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePan(_:))))

        borderLayer.borderWidth = 5
        borderLayer.frame = frame
        borderLayer.zPosition = 10
        borderLayer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        superview?.layer.addSublayer(borderLayer)

        backgroundLayer.frame = CGRect(x: frame.origin.x + 5, y: frame.origin.y + 5, width: frame.width - 10, height: frame.height - 10)
        backgroundLayer.zPosition = 20
        backgroundLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        superview?.layer.addSublayer(backgroundLayer);
    }

    @objc func handlePan(_ recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setValue(kCFBooleanTrue, forKey: kCATransactionDisableActions)

        let translation = recognizer.translation(in: self)
        frame = self.frame.offsetBy(dx: translation.x, dy: translation.y)
        recognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self)

        borderLayer.frame = borderLayer.frame.offsetBy(dx: translation.x, dy: translation.y)
        backgroundLayer.frame = backgroundLayer.frame.offsetBy(dx: translation.x, dy: translation.y)

        CATransaction.commit()
    }
}
```

---

Objective-C header:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MVMergingView : UIView

@end
```

Objective-C implementation:

```
#import "MVMergingView.h"

@interface MVMergingView ()

@property (strong) CALayer *borderLayer;
@property (strong) CALayer *backgroundLayer;

@end

@implementation MVMergingView

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    [self addGestureRecognizer:[[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)]];

    CALayer *borderLayer = [CALayer layer];
    borderLayer.borderWidth = 5.f;
    borderLayer.frame = self.frame;
    borderLayer.zPosition = 10;
    borderLayer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor.CGColor;
    self.borderLayer = borderLayer;
    [self.superview.layer addSublayer:borderLayer];

    CALayer *backgroundLayer = [CALayer layer];
    backgroundLayer.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x + 5.f, self.frame.origin.y + 5.f, self.frame.size.width - 10, self.frame.size.height - 10);
    backgroundLayer.zPosition = 20;
    backgroundLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor.CGColor;
    self.backgroundLayer = backgroundLayer;
    [self.superview.layer addSublayer:backgroundLayer];
}

- (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    [CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setValue:(id)kCFBooleanTrue forKey:kCATransactionDisableActions];

    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self];
    self.frame = CGRectOffset(self.frame, translation.x, translation.y);
    [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self];

    self.borderLayer.frame = CGRectOffset(self.borderLayer.frame, translation.x, translation.y);
    self.backgroundLayer.frame = CGRectOffset(self.backgroundLayer.frame, translation.x, translation.y);

    [CATransaction commit];
}

@end
```

---

Example repo: https://github.com/dimitarnestorov/MergingView

Comment: Wow, that's a really simple, yet powerful solution. Exactly what I was looking for. It's funny too because this is how I have my views set up already, one with content and then a border view behind it. Thank you!

Comment: @SerPounce be on the lookout for the **sibling** layers in the superview if you want the merging to work. You may also end up in some corner case related to that.

Comment: Wow, I struggled for hours until I came across this simple solution. It does exactly what I wanted to achieve, not more, not less

Comment: For the last 5 years I've been working as a web developer and my first thought was how would I do the same on the web. The answer was `z-index` and I searched if there was an alternative for Cocoa.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like your requirement to "merge" rather than overlap exists only because of the borders. If there were no borders, then there's no need for any merging; you simply overlap them. So the question becomes how to deal with the borders.

I'm thinking perhaps you can have a special UIView subclass (`MergingView`?) which would act as a parent of 2 views; a border view and a content view. Now that the border and content are in separate views, "merging" becomes trivial.

When we drop `A` on top of `B`, all we have to do is give A's border view and content view to B (so they are now subviews of B), and then send all of B's border views to the back.

You can then proceed to merge more with B, the procedure is the same.

Would this suit your use case? Happy to post code if needed.

Comment: I really appreciate you putting in thoughtful answers (I saw the one you posted yesterday before you edited and needed to some time to think about your solution before I responded). I misspoke when I said merge, apologies. Let me pause and think about this for a moment as maybe I'm framing the question wrong.